# OperatorPrecedenceParser throw exception about negative priority which I don't have

Tags: fparsec

I am creating a parser for a programming language based on the lambda-calculus. I added an infix operator and their precedence but the parser crashed with an error about negative priority. I am able to do the parsing of operator by hand, but it seem that I cannot get the priority right. So I thought that I may as well learn to use the OperatorPrecedenceParser.

I will show the code because I have no idea why it crash, since I don't have any negative priority.

The language AST

```
module MiniML
type Exp =
            | C of Cst 
            | Id of Id 
            | Lam of Id * Exp 
            | App of Exp * Exp 
            | Let of Id * Exp * Exp
            | Pair of Exp * Exp
            | If of Exp * Exp * Exp
and Cst  = I of int | B of bool | Unit | Nil
and Id   = string;;

let op = ["+"; 
      "-";
      "*"; 
      "/"; 
      "="; 
      "<"; 
      ">"; 
      "@"; 
      "and"; 
      "or"; 
      ","; 
      "::"
    ]
```

Here is the parser itself. It's my first time with parser combinator (and parsing) so if there is something terribly wrong, I'd like to know. Otherwise, just knowing why it crash would be enough.

```
open MiniML
open FParsec

let ws = spaces

let operator : Parser<MiniML.Id,unit> = op |> List.map pstring |> choice

let keyword : Parser<string,unit> = ["false";"true";"let";"end";"in";"if";"then";"else";"lam"] |> List.map pstring |> choice

let fstId = asciiLetter <|> pchar '_'

let restId = fstId <|> digit <|> pchar '''

let betweenPar p = between (pchar '(' .>> ws) (pchar ')' .>> ws) p

let cstB = (stringReturn "true"  (B true)) <|> (stringReturn "false" (B false))

let cstI = puint32 |>> (int >> I)

let cstU = stringReturn "()" Unit

let cstN = stringReturn "[]" Nil

let expC : Parser<Exp,unit> = cstB <|> cstI <|> cstU <|> cstN  |>> C

let expIdStr = notFollowedByL keyword "Cannot use keyword as variable" >>. 
                    notFollowedByL operator "Cannot use operator as variable" >>. 
                        many1CharsTill2 fstId restId (notFollowedBy restId)

let expId  : Parser<Exp,unit> = expIdStr |>> (MiniML.Exp.Id)

let exp, expRef = createParserForwardedToRef<Exp, unit>()

let expApp, expAppRef = createParserForwardedToRef<Exp, unit>()

let expLam : Parser<Exp,unit> = (pstring "lam" >>. ws >>. expIdStr .>> ws .>> pchar '.') .>> ws .>>. exp |>> Lam

let expLet = tuple3 (pstring "let" >>. ws >>. expIdStr .>> ws .>> pchar '=' .>> ws) (exp .>> ws .>> pstring "in" .>> ws) (exp .>> ws .>> pstring "end") |>> Let

let expIf = tuple3 (pstring "if" >>. ws >>. exp .>> ws) (pstring "then" >>. ws >>. exp .>> ws) (pstring "else" >>. ws >>. exp) |>> If

let closeEXP, closeEXPRef = createParserForwardedToRef<Exp, unit>()

let expBang = (pstring "!" >>% MiniML.Id "!") .>>. closeEXP |>> App

let buildList (el,ef)  = 
    let rec go l = match l with 
                       | (e::es) -> App(MiniML.Id "cons", Pair(e,go es))
                       | [] -> C Nil
    go (el @ [ef])

let expList = between (pchar '[' .>> ws) (pchar ']') (many (exp .>>? (ws .>> pchar ';' .>> ws)) .>>. exp .>> ws 
                |>> buildList )

do closeEXPRef := choice [expC ; expId ; expBang ; betweenPar exp ; expList]  .>> ws

do expAppRef := many1 closeEXP |>> (function (x::xs) -> List.fold (fun x y -> App(x,y)) x xs | [] -> failwith "Impossible")

let opOpp : InfixOperator<Exp,unit,unit> list = 
        [
          InfixOperator("*", ws, 6, Associativity.Left, fun x y -> App(MiniML.Id "*",Pair(x,y))); 
          InfixOperator("/", ws, 6, Associativity.Left, fun x y -> App(MiniML.Id "/",Pair(x,y)));
          InfixOperator("+", ws, 5, Associativity.Left, fun x y -> App(MiniML.Id "+",Pair(x,y))); 
          InfixOperator("-", ws, 5, Associativity.Left, fun x y -> App(MiniML.Id "-",Pair(x,y)));
          InfixOperator("::", ws,4, Associativity.Right, fun x y -> App(MiniML.Id "cons",Pair(x,y)));
          InfixOperator("=", ws, 3, Associativity.Left, fun x y -> App(MiniML.Id "=",Pair(x,y)));  
          InfixOperator("<", ws, 3, Associativity.Left, fun x y -> App(MiniML.Id "<",Pair(x,y)));  
          InfixOperator(">", ws, 3, Associativity.Left, fun x y -> App(MiniML.Id ">",Pair(x,y)));  
          InfixOperator("and", ws, 2, Associativity.Right, fun x y -> App(MiniML.Id "and",Pair(x,y))); 
          InfixOperator("or", ws, 1, Associativity.Right, fun x y -> App(MiniML.Id "or",Pair(x,y))); 
          InfixOperator(",", ws,0, Associativity.None, fun x y -> Pair(x,y) )
        ]

let opp = new OperatorPrecedenceParser<Exp,unit,unit>()
let expr = opp.ExpressionParser
let term = exp <|> betweenPar expr
opp.TermParser <- term
List.iter (fun x -> opp.AddOperator(x)) opOpp

do expRef := [expLam;expIf;expLet;expApp] |>  choice |> (fun p -> p .>>. opt (expOp operator) |>> binOp )

let mainExp = expr .>> eof
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample code doesn't seem to be complete, since `expOp` and `binOp` are not included.  When I run your code without the last two lines, the OPP throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` with the message "The operator precedence must be greater than 0." when the comma operator is added. The problem is that you specified 0 as the precedence for the comma operator.

Such problems are easier to diagnose when you use an IDE with a fully integrated debugger like Visual Studio.

Comment: For expOp and binOp they are not important. I forgot to erase them. They are for the hand rolled priority parser that I tried to make. I knew about the exception with the message. I thought that 0 was a valid priority. The doc says: The value is always greater zero. Is there a than missing?

Comment: Yes, the text in the documentation misses a "than". Thanks for pointing that out! I'm curious what made you think that zero was a permitted value. Did you interpret "greater (than) zero" as "non-negative"? (If I had wanted to allow 0, I'd have written "greater than or equal to zero".)

Comment: I've read it quickly. I don't know exactly how I misread it because indeed it seem clear. It might be because I am used to mathematician wich often write: Strictly greater than 0.